# How do I format a decimal data type to be used for price?

Tags: ruby

How do I format a decimal number?

I have `amount = 55.6`.

Is there a quick format that can be done in a single line so the output is `"55.60"`?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Formatted how?

Comment: Do you mean float? Decimal and float mean different things.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I am against your edit. what you think is just your imagination. You may or may not be correct. Only the OP knows. You shouldn't have made a will guess.

Comment: I was expecting "55.60" as my output. Sorry joined this forum today. Was not good at asking.

Comment: There are good reasons to not use decimals for currency/money, mostly because floating point values are notorious for having rounding errors. You should look into using fixed or integer values, with the appropriate math to put the decimal point where its needed. It seems obvious that a decimal or float would be appropriate, but it turns out wrong eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"%.2f" % amount #=> "55.60"
```

Hope this helps.